# String comparison not showing all matching results

Tags: java

I am working on a piece of code that is supposed to move elements of a class array (users) to a new array (ordered) if the user's "ordered" parameter is set as Y. The code will work for a few users, but for most it just skips over them. Why is this? Am I comparing the strings wrong or is there something else that I am not aware of?

```
 System.out.println("List of ordered phones:");
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(users[i].ordered.equals("Y")) {
            ordered[i] = users[i];
            System.out.println(ordered[i].name);
        }
    }
```

This is the loop in question. There isn't much to it other than the string comparison but even that is pretty straight forward.

Here is the entire program:

```
class User{
String name;
String phoneNum;
String current;
String type;
String requested;
String location;
String ordered;

User(String name, String phoneNum, String current, String type, String requested, String location, String ordered){
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    this.current = current;
    this.type = type;
    this.requested = requested;
    this.location = location;
    this.ordered = ordered;
}

public User() {
    
}
}
public class readWrite {

@SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    User[] users = new User[149];
    User[] ordered = new User[149];
    User[] received = new User[149];
    User[] trade = new User[149];
    int count = 0;
    
    File file = new File("I don't like showing my file path but it's correct");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        User user = new User(scan.nextLine(), scan.nextLine(), scan.nextLine(), scan.nextLine(), scan.nextLine(), scan.nextLine(), scan.nextLine());
        users[count] = user;
        count++;
    }
    
    User temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
            if(users[i].name.charAt(0) < users[j].name.charAt(0)) {
                temp = users[i];
                users[i] = users[j];
                users[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "." + " Name: " + users[i].name + "\n" + "Phone Number: " + users[i].phoneNum + "\n" + "Current Phone: " + users[i].current + "\n" + "Phone Type: " + users[i].type + "\n" + "Requested Phone: " + users[i].requested + "\n" + "Location: " + users[i].location + "\n" + "Ordered?: " + users[i].ordered + "\n\n");
    }
    
    System.out.println("List of ordered phones:");
    for(int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(users[i].ordered.equals("Y")) {
            ordered[i] = users[i];
            System.out.println(ordered[i].name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So if your array contains "ordered" users at, say, indexes 2, 5 and 8, where will those end up in the output array?

Comment: They will end up in both the new array and the old array. I am trying to make the list, then filter the list into other arrays based on the information from the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that they're skipped because they do not meet the following condition?

```
if(users[i].ordered.equals("Y"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That would be the issue. They should meet that condition but for some reason they are not. There are no extra spaces or anything, they just don't seem to want to go into the array.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the 3 for loops, instead of i, I needed to use "ord","rec", and "traded" so that no null entries go into the filtered arrays. When I was using i as the index it was inserting null values because i always grows even if the condition isn't met.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).